# Prometheus and Push Gateway how to keep state of incremental value over distributed processes

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I am dealing with many short lived same jobs (many instances of the same process per hour), for which Prometheus does not have time to scrape, which is a valid use-case for the [push gateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway)

My use case is that I want an error indication which count (of Gauge) these jobs.

As I understood, pushing a new value to the metric will override the previous one. And looking at the code for example in a python library for `Gauge.inc()` takes its value of the current process which is reset for each job run, hence, not providing a total count.

I see the following options to create a proper counter:

- add a `job_instance` tag and sum when creating dashboards/alerts. The issue I see is that the metrics are not cleared so, running many jobs/instances will blow up the cache.
- to overcome blowing up the cache, send delete requests periodically - this feels like a major hack
- query the metric upfront and increment. Besides possible timing/concurrency and dependency issues, I did not found an endpoint exposing these.
- use any other different approach

What would be the proper way to create a counter which can be counted over multiple same process?

Comment: maybe you can add callback to your process. that is to say `future.add_done_callback(func)` and this function being the one having the `Gauge.inc()`

Comment: I'd like to note, that while this is in fact a valid case for Pushgateway, Prometheus' best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#batch-jobs) recommend the following: "For batch jobs that run very often (say, more often than every 15 minutes), you should consider converting them into daemons and handling them as offline-processing jobs."

Comment: @markalex: yes, that would be nice - however the architecture does not allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use any other different approach

Use [prom-aggregation-gateway](https://github.com/zapier/prom-aggregation-gateway) instead. It's tailer made for this kind of use case. From the README:

> According to https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/:
>
> > The Pushgateway never forgets series pushed to it and will expose them
> > to Prometheus forever...
> >
> > The latter point is especially relevant when multiple instances of a
> > job differentiate their metrics in the Pushgateway via an instance
> > slabel or similar.
>
> This restriction makes the Prometheus pushgateway inappropriate for
> the use case of accepting metrics from a client-side web app, so we
> created this one to aggregate counters from multiple senders.
>
> Prom-aggregation-gateway presents a similar API but does not attempt
> to be a drop-in replacement.